# plotMA function issue: can not circle genes

Tags: rna-seq, deseq2, figure-reproduction

I am trying to make `MA`-plot for my `bulk-RNA-seq` dataset and experiencing issues with it. I just copy-pasted the code that can be found here:

https://f1000research.com/articles/4-1070/v2

which is:

```
library("DESeq2")
plotMA(resLFC1, ylim=c(-5,5))
topGene <- rownames(resLFC1)[which.min(resLFC1$padj)]
with(resLFC1[topGene, ], {
  points(baseMean, log2FoldChange, col="dodgerblue", cex=2, lwd=2)
  text(baseMean, log2FoldChange, topGene, pos=2, col="dodgerblue")
})
```

However, I am not getting the right plot with the top gene circled, but the following one:

[image]

Maybe it is a bug in the `plotMA` function, not sure. How can I reproduce the figure from the publication?

Comment: Are you sure that resLFC1 is created as stated in the article ? There seems to be a lot more points than in the article. Also, do you get any error or message?

Comment: Are you sure the weird double quotes (“ versus ") are not the problem?

Comment: I corrected them, of course. `Rstudio` complains about it right away.

Comment: Your plot shows **all** genes as DE (red points). That’s suspicious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that the fold-change of the `topGene` is greater than 5. Consequently, the circle is being drawn and the text produced, but they're outside the bounds of the plot (the bounds don't update if you add a circle and text label). Look at the `log2FoldChange` column of `resLFC1[topGene, ]` and increase the bounds to encompass that.